Desenfoque automático en inputs de React
Tengo un formulario bastante complejo en el que se divide en partes y los voy ocultando o mostrando de acuerdo al paso en el que se encuentre el usuario. Hay cards dinámicos con inputs en su interior y puedo darle clic al botón de agregar, para agregar más cards. El problema es que en los inputs de las cards, al escribir un caracter, se desenfoca automáticamente. Deduje que puede ser problemas de re-renders e intenté paliar ese problema, pero tampoco funcionó. Lo mismo con useRef para tratar de no perder el foco. ¿Alguien más tuvo este problema o sabe a qué podría deberse? No dejo el código, ya que solo quiero saber posibles problemas porque el formulario tiene distintas partes y es bastante complejo.
